# Google Cloud web app not displaying custom Python code

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, web-applications

I currently have a "working" web app through Google Cloud's App Engine.
The only thing that is being displayed when I visit my web app is "Welcome to my Python program!" that I have in my index.html file.

I'm trying to display the rest of the Python code that prints some strings regarding time.
What I have in my files isn't working and I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. I've tried messing around with the Python code as I believe that is the issue. Maybe I'm not placing the call to the function in the right place?

Here is what I have as far as files go:

requirements.txt

```
Flask==2.0.2
pytz==2020.1
gunicorn==19.3.0
```

app.yaml

```
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app

runtime_config:
    python_version: 3

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: /.*
  script: auto

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

main.py

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

def all_about_time():
    #Prints local date.
    current_time = datetime.now()
    local_date = datetime.strftime(current_time, '%b %d, %Y')
    print('Today\'s date is: '  + str(local_date))
        
    #Prints out the time on the east coast. Helps give context on market hours.    
    eastern_time = datetime.strftime(current_time.astimezone(pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')), '%I:%M %p')
    print('Time on the East Coast is currently: ' + eastern_time)
    
    #This logic block dictates whether the market is closed or open. So far does not account for holidays.
    day_of_week = datetime.strftime(current_time.astimezone(pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')), '%A')
    dt_east = int(datetime.strftime(current_time.astimezone(pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')), '%H%M'))
    if 930 <= dt_east <= 1600 and (day_of_week != 'Saturday' and day_of_week != 'Sunday'):
        print('The market is open!')
    else:
        print('The market is closed.')

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    all_about_time()
    return render_template('index.html')
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='script.js') }}"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>MyPythonProgram</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome to my Python Program!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the last statement in `all_about_time` to:

```py
    if 930 <= dt_east <= 1600 and (day_of_week != 'Saturday' and day_of_week != 'Sunday'):
        return('open')
    else:
        return('closed')
```

Then change the following:

```py
@app.route("/")
def hello():
    status = all_about_time()
    return render_template('index.html', status=status)
```

Then change `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='script.js') }}"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>MyPythonProgram</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>The market is {{ status }}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

I encourage to read Flask's (excellent) [documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/) to understand how it works.

I've not run your code but, assuming that `all_about_time` time works, it prints a string to (standard) output. The `hello` run invokes `all_about_time` (which prints the string) and *then* (importantly) the function renders the `index.html` template which produces the output you observe `Welcome to my Python Program!`. Even though `all_about_time` printed something, the output went to the console and was **not** included in the page that was rendered in the browser.

With minimal changes:

1. `all_about_time` returns a string (either `open` or `closed`).
2. `hello` invokes `all_about_time` and assigns the result (either `open` or `closed`) to `status`.
3. `status` is then passed to the template to be rendered
4. The template now includes a variable `{{ status }}` which will be replaced with the actual value of `status` i.e. (hopefully) `open` or `closed`

Comment: Thank you for that. I will try those edits. What about the other print statements that I have in there? Thanks for the link for the documentation.

Comment: You're welcome! Please leave the other `print` statements in there to demonstrate the point. If you run the Flask server locally, you will see that the output of the `print` statements goes to the server's output (rather than the browser page). If you want, you could:
```python3
    if 930 <= dt_east <= 1600 and (day_of_week != 'Saturday' and day_of_week != 'Sunday'):
        status = 'open'
    else:
        status = 'closed'

print('The market is {status}'.format(status=status))
return status
```